# Failed to deploy function: function name(s) can only contain letters, numbers, hyphens, and not exceed 62 characters in length

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using [group functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions) when giving name to my function as per that documentation

so in my `index.ts` I have code like this

```
export * as callableMainApp from "./callable_functions/main_app/callable_main_app";
```

and then in my `callable_main_app.ts` file, I have code like this

```
export const deleteAnonymousAccount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const anonymousUID = data.anonymousUID;

    try {

        await authController.deleteAnonymousUser(anonymousUID);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});
```

I only want to deploy this one only function, so I expect I can deploy this one function using

```
firebase deploy --only functions:callableMainApp-deleteAnonymousAccount
```

but I always get this error:

> Error: [object Object] function name(s) can only contain letters,
> numbers, hyphens, and not exceed 62 characters in length

I believe I have met the requirement but why I still get the error? am I missing something?

I am using

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.10.0"
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
firebase tools: 9.14.0
Node 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use dot notation instead.

e.g.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:callableMainApp.deleteAnonymouseAccount
```

relevant issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1735

quote from [firebase doc](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions):

> Or you can target a specific function within a group by running the
> following command:
>
> `firebase deploy --only functions:groupA.function1,functions:groupB.function4`